# Why getting handle or declare error, when already declared?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

This is the code sample and I am getting an error "must be caught or declare to
be  thrown" but I have

already handled the IOException. So can you please tell why the error is populating. The code also

follows the handle and declare rule.

```
public void rethrow() throws SQLException, IOException {
    try {
        couldThrowAnException();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e = new IOException();
        throw e;            //Error: must be caught or declare to be thrown
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheLostMind: he rethrows an IOException, while he has a throws IOException. I think that's his question

Comment: @Aman you caught it as Exception e. Which means, it is declared as an Exception, not as an IOException, and for that, you don't have a throws clause

Comment: By the way you are consuming your own exception without logging it. So you will loss the cause of exception.

Comment: even if we are not having throws Exception, it will compile fine if I remove e = new IOException();

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are running into is that the compiler deals with the variable declaration type, not the type you assign to the variable.
The variable is of type `Exception`, which is not part of the `throws` clause.

If you change the `catch()` clause to match `IOException`, it will compile.

I'd suggest you read [the Exceptions Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) of the [Java Language Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html).

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this entire `try...catch` is redundant... (+1)

Comment: @BoristheSpider true, but I'm hoping this is obvious to the OP :-)

Comment: From java 7, if I remove the e = new IOException(); it will compile and run fine.

Comment: @Aman may I ask what the point, if any, of the above code is?

Comment: @Boris the Spide I am preparing for OCJP exam, so I got this question

Comment: @Aman if you just catch and rethrow, I am guessing the compiler inlines that

Answer (score 0):

You handled IOException but you are throwing Exception(not IOException ) from catch block.
So you have to add Exception in throws clause

or

catch IOException instead of Exception in the catch block

Answer (score 0):

```
public void rethrow() throws SQLException, IOException {
    try {
        couldThrowAnException();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e = new IOException();
        throw e;            //Error: must be caught or declare to be thrown
    }
}
```

Although, it makes no sens to cathc it and throw it...

A far better way would be:

```
public void rethrow() {
    try {
        couldThrowAnException();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        //do something when you encounter the io-error
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        //do something when you encounter the sql-error
    }
}
```

Comment: Especially not with the e = new IOException(); in it, since you'll be hiding the original exception